# Singleton instance of component in vuejs

Tags: vue.js, singleton, openlayers

I have a basic openlayers map in a vue component:

```
<template>
  <div id="map" style="width: 300px; height: 200px;"></div>
</template>

<script>
import Map from 'ol/Map.js';
import View from 'ol/View.js';
import TileLayer from 'ol/layer/Tile.js';
import OSM from 'ol/source/OSM.js';
export default {
  mounted() {
     var map = new Map({
        layers: [
          new TileLayer({
            source: new OSM(),
          }),
        ],
        target: 'map',
        view: new View({
          center: [0, 0],
          zoom: 2,
        }),
      });
  },
};
</script>
```

Now I would like to reuse this component on multiple pages on my SPA, because I would like to avoid the tiles reloading and maintain features on the map. Normally (if not a map, but just general data) I could just remain the data state in a vuex store or alike, but since this openlayers object is bound to this specific 'map' div, I can´t see that it is possible. 
I´ve tried the vue  element, but no luck. 
So how to get around this?

Comment: You can move a map between divs https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/teleport.html

Comment: Ah, teleport, never thought of that! I was thinking of a vue-like solution. Thanks!

Comment: What about keeping it as a parent component and showing all other as childs?

Comment: Can you please elaborate this @SzymonSasin, or maybe an example?

Comment: ... and actually I cannot use the teleport solution as @Mike suggested, since the openlayers I use is wrapped in another component which creates an overlay on the Openlayers map. So while this teleport solution is great, I cannot use it for my purpose. Instead i need to make this component move to different places in the DOM in some way.